# Updating a Table after some values are inserted into it in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert-update

I am trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 which updates a table after some values are inserted into the table.

My stored procedure takes the values from a DMV and stores them in a table. In the same procedure after insert query, I have written an update query for the same table.

Insert results are populated fine, but the results of updates are getting lost.

But when I try to do only inserts in the stored procedure and I execute the update query manually everything is fine.

Why it is happening like this?

Comment: Can you provide sample code which you have worked on..

Comment: Stored procedure is not the best approach in this scenario, `Triggers' are supposed to be used here.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad - No my need is a stored procedure only. I know about using triggers also, but i need to do some calculations from DMV's so i am using SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should not be a problem in this.

below code working as expected.

```
create procedure dbo.test

as

begin 

create table #temp (
name varchar(100) ,
id int
)

insert #temp
select name ,
       id 
from master..sysobjects

update #temp

set name='ALL Same'

from #temp

select * from #temp

drop table #temp

end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), sample of `AFTER UPDATE` trigger is below:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_MyTriggerName]
   ON [dbo].[MyTableName] AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --if MyColumnName is updated the do..
    IF UPDATE (MyColumnName) 
    BEGIN

        UPDATE MyTableName
        SET    AnotherColumnInMyTable = someValue
        FROM   MyTableName  
               INNER JOIN Inserted  
               ON MyTableName.PrimaryKeyColumn = Inserted.PrimaryKeyColumn 
    END
END
```